# Почему после getSupportFragmentManager.replace(), фрагмент который был заменен остается доступным

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Вызываю фрагмент таким методом

```
    public void showFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .replace(R.id.layout1, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получаю наложение фрагмента на фрагмент, но не замену

Comment: Изначальный фрагмент у вас, случаем, не в xml прописан? Прямо в разметке активити?

Comment: фрагмент подключается через viewPager, а тот в свою очередь прописан в разметке активити

Comment: Т.е. вы поверх фрагмента во вьюПежере хотите отобразить другой фрагмент? Если да, то даже не пробуйте пытаться так сделать, а сразу вместо фрагмента запускайте активити с ним. Иначе - потратите много времени впустую.